# Magento 2 Cron display out of stock product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-cron

I want to get list of all the products for particular categories irrespective of OUT OF STOCK or IN STOCK using cron.

Currently, if i execute the cron it list only IN STOCK product. I don't want to change the setting in backend "Display out of stock product" to "Yes".

Please advice...

Comment: Which cron do you run and can you paste the code on how you are getting products

Comment: @priyank, 

<group id="default">
    <job name="productimport" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\Product" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/15 * * * *</schedule>
    </job> 
</group>


$productCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
  
   $collection = $productCollection->create();